# Skid Steer Drive Plugin unable to find joints when it is included in a sdf

Tags: skid-steer, gazebo-model, gazebo-plugin, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am creating a new robot model, to do so I include the mobile platform and the sensors in the robot's sdf.

When I add this robot an SkidSteerDrivePlugin error[1] appears saying it is unable to find the joints.

If instead of the robot's sdf[2] I launch only the platform's sdf[3] then it works.

I tried unsuccessfuly to:

- move the plugin tag up to the robot's model
- change the joints to segway_rmp400::the_joint
- both at same time
- find the patched plugin mentioned in ["question/3311/skidsteerdriveplugin"](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3311/skidsteerdriveplugin)

In the ["question/3311/skidsteerdriveplugin"](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3311/skidsteerdriveplugin) something similar happens because the plugin has the joint names hard coded. I suppose the problem is there

Should I have to create a world with all the sdf inside without using includes?

Thanks in advance!

[1] The error

```
Error [SkidSteerDrivePlugin.cc:51] Unable to find the right_front joint in model teo.
Error [SkidSteerDrivePlugin.cc:51] Unable to find the right_rear joint in model teo.
Error [SkidSteerDrivePlugin.cc:51] Unable to find the left_front joint in model teo.
Error [SkidSteerDrivePlugin.cc:51] Unable to find the left_rear joint in model teo.
```

[2] The robot's SDF

```
 <model name="teo">
   <include>
     <uri>model://segway_rmp400</uri>
     <name>segway_rmp400</name>
     <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
   </include>
   ...
```

[3] The platform's SDF

```
<model name="segway_rmp400">
  <link name="chassis">..</link>
  ...
  <plugin name="SkidSteerDrivePlugin" filename="libSkidSteerDrivePlugin.so">
    <right_front>right_front</right_front>
    <right_rear>right_rear</right_rear>
    <left_front>left_front</left_front>
    <left_rear>left_rear</left_rear>
    <max_force>100.0</max_force>
  </plugin>
</model>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4910/skid-steer-drive-plugin-unable-to-find-joints-when-it-is-included-in-a-sdf/) by [Martí Morta - IRI](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23/mart%C3%AD-morta---iri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can try plugin from gazebo_ros_pkgs documented here: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins#Skid_Steering_Drive. Let me know in case of any problems with this plugin.

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) with karma: 62 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martí Morta - IRI](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23/mart%C3%AD-morta---iri/) on 2013-11-05**:
Thanks I didn't find this, I am going to try it asap :)